# Azure RAM Memory transfer rate

Tags: azure, ram

I am trying to model how my app will perform on Azure RAM on the H / DSv2 series VM's. I need to know the memory transfer rate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're in a hypervisor. Whatever hardware info you're reading from the guest OS is probably a lie. Just find a consistent way to benchmark your workload across different VM families.

CPU is probably the only thing not obscured by the hypervisor:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 63
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz
```